# MySQL request returns an empty result on String

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

I have a table with vouchers for reservation system. And when I try to select a row by code string it returns me an empty result. But I just ctrl+C the string which I wanna to select, which is really strange.

[Here I'm copying code string to select it after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ9Pi.png)

And after I try to select it with:

```
SELECT * FROM `vouchers` WHERE code = "S723-452Q-3486"
```

And it returns me an empty result

[Here it returns me an empty result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET7Fq.png)

But! When I edit row with a space after the code string and remove it right after it starts to SELECT it.

[Add a space after the code- save it, and remove it after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbqtp.png)

[Returns the result of SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYrH.png)

So I really don't know why it's so, but probably when I show you how I added those rows into the DB it may help you to understand.

I put multiply rows into `<textarea id="codes" name="codes" rows="4" cols="35" required></textarea>` and after it in PHP separete each row with

`

```
//var_dump($_POST);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$startTime = $_POST['startTime'];
$endTime = $_POST['endTime'];
$timeAvailable = $startTime."'".$endTime;

$max_times = $_POST['max_times'];
$expDate = $_POST['expDate'];
$ppl_amount = $_POST['ppl_amount'];
$days = "";

if ($_POST['Monday']) {
    $days=$days."Monday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Tuesday']) {
    $days=$days."Tuesday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Wednesday']) {
    $days=$days."Wednesday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Thursday']) {
    $days=$days."Thursday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Friday']) {
    $days=$days."Friday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Saturday']) {
    $days=$days."Saturday'";
    # code...
}
if ($_POST['Sunday']) {
    $days=$days."Sunday'";
    # code...
}
$days = rtrim($days, "'");
//echo $days;
$codes = "";

if (isset($_POST['codes'])) {
    $codes = explode("\n", $_POST["codes"]);
}


foreach ($codes as $code) {
    $voucherQuery = 'INSERT INTO vouchers (name, discount, daysAvailable, timeAvailable, code, max_times, used, expiration_date, ppl_amount)
                    VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$discount.'", "'.$days.'", "'.$timeAvailable.'", "'.$code.'", "'.$max_times.'", 0, "'.$expDate.'", "'.$ppl_amount.'")';
    $result = $db_handle->getResult($voucherQuery); }
```

`

So when I added it to DB everything looks fine, but when I have tried to use one voucher it shows me an error, because SELECT which I use in PHP code returns an empty result, then I tried to directly enter SQL query into MySQL and got the same result.

I copy codes from excel table and ctrl+V it into textarea.

Comment: how exactly does the content of your `$_POST["codes"]` look like? do you maybe need to explode it by `\r\n`or something else, instead of just `\n` ?

Comment: As @Tagas said, I think you will find some white space character is sneaky stored with the data, try to show the hex of the column by `select hex(code)`

Comment: @Accountantم So I used another voucher code to do `SELECT HEX(  `code` ) 
FROM  `vouchers` 
WHERE voucherid =1172
LIMIT 0 , 30`  and it shows me 53 32 38 32 2D 33 39 37 4C 2D 33 33 37 39 0D when the normal code is 53 32 38 32 2D 33 39 37 4C 2D 33 33 37 39. So the difference on the end is 0D which is '\r' I think. So  I think that's why it doesn't want to SELECT it.

Comment: @Tagas So I think so also. Because when I transfer the code into HEX from the table it shows me 0D on the end, which is `\r` I will try to add it to explode

Answer (score 0):

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Reference [PHP trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

The carriage return is hidden inside the excel cell so when you copy it comes along with it or even if you import CSV. There are numerous ways to deal with it but the one I use is [PHP trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). It will clean all unwanted characters and spaces.

```
if (isset($_POST['codes'])) { 
$codes = explode("\n", $_POST["codes"]);}
```

Instead of explode, use trim().